# Why am I getting true for a reversed string, which is not equal in Java?

Tags: java, string

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder("abb");
        StringBuilder stringReverse = string.reverse();
    
        if(string.toString().equals(stringReverse.toString())){
            System.out.println(true);
            return;
        }
    
        System.out.println(false);
    }
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/SR8FJO).

I get the output of the above code as 'true'. But the reversed string is 'bba'. How is 'bba' equal to 'abb'? Please could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reverse()` returns the *same* object (not a new `StringBuilder`).

Your code:

```
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder("abb");
StringBuilder stringReverse = string.reverse();
```

is identical to:

```
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder("abb");
string.reverse();
StringBuilder stringReverse = string; // Same object!
```

Answer (score 3):

`StringBuilder#reverse()` reverses the text in the StringBuilder itself (and returns the same). Print out the values held by string and stringReverse to see for yourself:

```
System.out.println("string: " + string);
System.out.println("stringReverse: " + stringReverse);
```

returns

```
string: bba
stringReverse: bba
```

Even more importantly, the [API for StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) tells you this:

> Causes this character sequence to be replaced by the reverse of the sequence.

Also, the string and stringReverse are **one and the same object**, in other words, this:

```
System.out.println("stringReverse  == string: " + (stringReverse == string));
```

will print out `true`

Answer (score 1):

As `StringBuilder` is mutable, when you are calling `reverse` you are actually reversing the original `StringBuilder`.

Try

```
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder("abb");
StringBuilder stringReverse = new StringBuilder(string).reverse();
     
System.out.println(string.toString());
System.out.println(stringReverse.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation...I got the answer!! :)

Answer (score 0):

The first three Answers are correct. One of them should be accepted. I will add one small thought about the importance of naming.

## Naming can confuse or clarify

This Question is an example of how poor naming can lead you astray.

Naming your first `StringBuilder` with the word `string` leads one to think of that var as referencing a mutable `String` object when in fact it references a mutable `StringBuilder`. Naming something like `firstStringBuilder` would avoid this problem of being easy to misread.

```java
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder("abb");
//            ^^^^^^ No, this is not an immutable `String` object reference.
```

Alternate naming clarifies.

```java
StringBuilder firstStringBuilder = new StringBuilder( "abb" );
StringBuilder reversedStringBuilder = firstStringBuilder.reverse();  // Both vars ( `firstStringBuilder` & `reversedStringBuilder` ) reference the very same single `StringBuilder` object. 

if( firstStringBuilder.toString().equals( reversedStringBuilder.toString() ) ){
    System.out.println( "firstStringBuilder & reversedStringBuilder are equal because they both point to the very same single StringBuilder object. So the result of calling `.toString` twice on the same object is the same." );
    return;
}

System.out.println( "Not equal" );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/K58nBR).

> firstStringBuilder & reversedStringBuilder are equal because they both point to the very same single StringBuilder object. So the result of calling `.toString` twice on the same object is the same.